# java code when copied to servlet wont work at all

Tags: java, servlets

This method below when placed in a class works fine, but when is pasted in a servlet code, and called, will not work at all.
The error message generated is:
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

How do I fix the above error message? The database is registered with the system properly, and is working if this code is in a regular class.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
public static int sendMyQUERY(String q) {
    int i = 0;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement s = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String database = "jdbc:odbc:SS";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
        s = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        i = s.executeUpdate(q);
        s.close();
        conn.close();
        return i;
    } catch (Exception ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        return i;
    }
}// endMethod
```

This is the servlet code.
By not working I mean that the query wont get executed, and cause I cant see the printStackTrace(), I dont know the reason as well.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class SS extends HttpServlet {        
    public static int sendMyQuery( String q ){
        int i=0;
        Connection conn=null;
        Statement s=null;
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String database= "jdbc:odbc:SS";
            conn= DriverManager.getConnection( database,"","" );
            s = conn.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
            i=s.executeUpdate(q);
            s.close(); conn.close();
            return i;
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            return i;
        }
    }//End

    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException{
        PrintWriter pw= response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");    
        int j = sendMyQuery("CREATE TABLE "+users+" ( id AUTOINCREMENT, username varchar(255) , pass varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY(id) ) ");    
        pw.println(" <h1> "+ Integer.toString(j) + " query response ");

    }//doGet
}//class
```

In above code, the table wont get created at all. Like the query was never sent.

Comment: What does "will not work", mean?

Comment: show us the servlet code.

Comment: !!Red alert!! SQL Injection detected!

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question with the servlet code. By not working I mean that the query is not send to database. Errors are not generated while compiling.

Comment: Check your server log for the stacktrace... If you are using an IDE it will most probably be displayed in the associated console..

Comment: Please, learn how to properly indent your code.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong here?` <- Ignoring a decade of experience that says, "Do not, under any circumstance, attempt to manually manage JDBC connections directly in Servlet code." Find a web framework and learn it.

Comment: Hi, if someone please knows another way of sending a query when using a servlet, please post it as answer. May be a working code if possible. Many Thanks

Comment: I think the web server runs under different username, so it doesn't see the same environment as yours while you are running it from a "regular class".

Answer (score 0):

To see what you are doing, do this:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class SS extends HttpServlet {        
    public static int sendMyQuery( String q ) throws Exception {
        int i=0;
        Connection conn=null;
        Statement s=null;
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        String database= "jdbc:odbc:SS";
        conn= DriverManager.getConnection( database,"","" );
        s = conn.createStatement( ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        i=s.executeUpdate(q);
        s.close(); conn.close();
        return i;
    }//End

    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws IOException{
        PrintWriter pw= response.getWriter();
        try {
            int j = sendMyQuery("CREATE TABLE "+users+" ( id AUTOINCREMENT, username varchar(255) , pass varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY(id) ) ");    
            response.setContentType("text/html");    
            pw.println(" <h1> "+ Integer.toString(j) + " query response ");
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");    
            ee.printStackTrace(pw);
        }
    }//doGet
}//class
```

Comment: This is the error message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified.  If java is not able to find the database, then why is this code working in a regular class?

Comment: Does the servlet container run as a different user than you? If not, I'd suggest not using odbc, but the vendor-supplied jdbc library (unless, ofc, you need ODBC naming)